# Are there so drawbacks to use many to many mysql relationships with set type columns?

Tags: php, mysql

I just wonder if there are some good practises with using **SET TYPE for many to many relationships** ?

I have a user table. Each user has his hobbies (many to many), books etc.
 and the goal is :

1) insert, update, delete hobbies for an user

2) search for someone hobbies (ex: those whose hobbies are cinema)

It looks at first glance that using SET type is very easy to achieve.

Has someone enough experience with that and tell me what drawbacks may be ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

Thee are several drawbacks to using a `set`.  First, it limits the number of elements in the set.  For certain applications, this may not be an issue.  However, SQL many-to-many relationships are typically "0/1-to-n" and not "0/1-to-n where n is some number less than the maximum number allowed in the set implementation in MySQL".

A second drawback is that sets are quite MySQL-specific.  This makes it more difficult to port the code to another database.

And perhaps the most important limitation is that association tables (the alternative) are really the "SQL" way of doing things.  They are very powerful and a good idea.  I worry that sets will quickly lead you to storing values in comma delimited lists -- an even worse idea than using sets.

There are some circumstances where sets are useful.  In particular, they are quite efficient, so for certain performance-critical applications, they are preferable.